# Problem checking the name of a file in php

Tags: php, xml, file-upload, filenames, strcmp

I am writing a PHP page to convert an uploaded file to XML. I only want to convert the news file to XML. The only file that ever needs to be converted is news.htm. I have narrowed my problem down to this if statement. What is wrong with it?

```
$fileName = basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name'] );

if( strcmp( $fileName, "news.htm") == 0 )
(
    //convertToXML();
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use curly braces around the body of the `if` statement, instead of parentheses:

```
if( strcmp( $fileName, "news.htm") == 0 )
{
    //convertToXML();
}
```

Comment: I cant believe I didnt notice that... I guess I need to get my eyes checked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$fileName = basename( stripslashes( $_FILES['uploaded']['name'] ) );
```

Comment: No. I have printed it out and I know it doesnt include slashes.

Comment: Just a note, PHP does some weird stuff with the super globals. Sometimes I've had to do stripslashes on POST and GET variables to get preg_replace to work as expected on them.